Extracting RSA private key from an android app
I need an RSA private key from a unity based android app. Is it possible to extract it somehow with any tools like frida or ghidra?
Already tried to mitm-attack the app and disable the SSL pinning, which didn't work out for me.

AFAIK Unity uses .Net/Mono -> Xamarin/MAUI. Therefore first starting point would be extracting the dll files containing the APK file if the haven't been compiled to aot format. Decompiling those dll files using ILSpy you may be already able to where the private key comes from and how to extract it.

Can I debug the method somehow if i know the lib where it comes from and the address that it has?

If it is a Xamarin/MAUI based app debugging with frida is possible but very complicated as you have to deal with the Mono framework. For Xamarin + frida there are some samples online.

Why do you think the app has any private keys in it? I would expect it doesn't have any.

I know it since all encrypted data has tls protocol, already checked it in wireshark

TLS does not require a persistent private key on the client side, only on the server side. ephemeral private keys are generated on the fly, used once, and then discarded.

So, is there any other way I can decrypt them excluding pre-master key method?
